# Why do my images become a broken link and disappear from website when I put them into a images sub folder in Atom?

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

So I have my main HTML folder, then it also encompasses a img folder which I want to keep images in so it's more tidy but as I do this the images become broken links and disappear from the website. Whereas if I keep them in the main HTML folder they show fine, but the img folder is within the HTML folder so why does this happen? And how do I fix it? Thank you

Please note I'm on about the folders on the left side within Atom (Atom's own folders not PC folders).

Answer (score 1):

Your path is probably off is the issue.

Check you html tag `<img src="/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain">`

Good resource:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp